# mfs service stopped running and cldb not coming up in MapR Cluster

Tags: mapr

We have a 3 nodes `MapR`  cluster. All 3 nodes have `zookeeper` running and the 1st node has `CLDB`, webserver and `ResourceManager` apart from zookeeper.

The cluster was up and running , however the 1st node went down yesterday post which the `CLDB` service is not coming up.

- The `MFS` service is also not seen to be running on the same node.
- We tried to get the latest epoch of cldb by giving the command maprcli dump zkinfo -json , but this gives me error:

  ```
  "Unable to obtain the ZooKeeper connection string”.
  ```
- Warden log also gives the same zookeeper error.
- I have already checked the zookeeper qstatus and it shows running .
- We have ensured that the 1st node has zookeeper as leader and the other 2 nodes are follower, but still restarting cldb gives the same error and MFS service also doesn't start.

Do not know how to debug and how to get the cluster up and running.

thanks,

Comment: This issue was sorted out by mapR support team. thanks to them. the issue was with the env.sh file . there was an extra '/' in one of the classpath settings.

Comment: Please provide a solution if you have one.